# Sending the Session

Tags: java, google-app-engine, session

I am currently doing a system on Google App Engine and am very new to it, I am developing using the Java plattform . I have a problem about sending the session object between servlets. I have already enabled sessions on the appengine.webxml. I can send the session object from my login page to a VIEW page but after which the session object cannot be passed any longer.

Any possible answers?

Comment: You should include an example how you are working with the session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to "pass" a session object from one Servlet to another. The session object can always be retrieved via the `HttpServletRequest` e.g. like this `HttpSession session = request.getSession();`. In JSPs (I guess that's your view technology) you can access the session via the implicit variable `session`.

To make sure your session doesn't expire to early set an appropriate value for `<session-timeout/>` in your `web.xml`.